# Leaflet Mobile Not Working

Tags: leaflet, mobile

Trying to get this to work on a mobile device. Works fine on a computer. Anybody have any suggestions as to why it wont show up on my phone?

```
</body></html>
    <head><title>Leaflet Mobile App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css">
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Start GeoJSON Data Load -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="data/heatpoints1.js"></script>
    <!-- End GeoJSON Data Load -->

    <style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

    var map = L.map('map');
    L.tileLayer('http://otile{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg', { format: 'image/png', minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 19, opacity: 1, subdomains: '1234' }).addTo(map);

    function onLocationFound(e) {
    var mydate = new Date(e.timestamp);
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup(mydate.toString());
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert("Unable to find your location. You may need to enable Geolocation.");
    }

    //  Start Heat Map
    var golf = L.heatLayer(golfcoursePoints,{
        radius: 25,
        blur: 25, 
        maxZoom: 17
    //  gradient: {
    //      0.1: '#ffffb2',
    //      0.3: '#fd8d3c',
    //      0.8: '#fd8d3c', 
    //      0.9: '#f03b20',
    //      1.0: '#bd0026'
    //  }
    });
    //  End Heat Map


    var basemaps = {
        "Map": map
        };

    var overlayMaps = {
        "Maryland Golf Courses": golf
        };

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom:12});    

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(basemaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: true}).addTo(map);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You may just need to initialize the map with some default view, like `var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 0)`. Otherwise it won't display anything until it gets a location.

Comment: Is the first line right? </body></html> looks like two closing tags. Should be a doctype and an opening tag. If that's not a pasting error putting your code on here it might just be mobile browsers being fussier.

Comment: I tried both of those and still no luck. Works fine on my laptop but can't get it to work on my phone

Comment: Maybe try a fixed height for `#map` (e.g. in pixels rather than %). At least to see if it makes any difference. I recall that it did the trick for someone else, but I cannot find the related post unfortunately.